# Calculate flight time

Tags: timezone

I am working now on a function ot calculate the flight time. I have a very strange problem, because it is a new domain for me.

Here is one example:

Outward: 
25.02.2011 11:45 Cologne - Las Vegas 26.02.2011 21:18

Return: 
18.03.2011 09:49 Las Vegas - Cologne 19.03.2011 11:05

For this flight Kayak is showing
Outward: 18:33 hours
Return: 17:16 hours

Cologne is GMT +01:00
Las Vegas is America/Los_Angeles timezone -> -08:00

But in the example the flight durariion for the outward flight is calculated with -8 hours offset for Las Vegas and for the return flight with -7 hours offset for Las Vegas. Why?

I have see the timezones here: http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/timeZones.txt

Has anyone any idea?

Thanks
Nik

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I solve the problem. Thanks for the advice to convert both dates to UTC/GMT first.

Here is the trick:

$reset_timezone = date_default_timezone_get();

// convert the first time
date_default_timezone_set($timezone_identifier1);
$time1   = $date_from.' '.$time_from;
$gmtime1 = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($time1));

// convert the second time
date_default_timezone_set($timezone_identifier2);
$time2 = $date_to.' '.$time_to;
$gmtime2 = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($time2));

// reset the timezone again
date_default_timezone_set($reset_timezone);

--> here calculate the difference < --

Hope it helps anyone else!

Cheers
Nik

Comment: If this is the answer to your question, then accept it (click the tickmark next to it), that way your accept percentage goes up and more people will be happy to answer your questions. It is ok to accept your own answers (you won't get any reputation for it though).

Answer (score 5):

It's because Daylight Savings Time doesn't start on the same date everywhere.

[Las Vegas: DST starts on Sunday, 13 March 2011](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=127)
[Cologne: DST starts on Sunday, 27 March 2011](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=311)

So since your return flight is on the 18th of March, Las Vegas will be in DST, but Cologne won't be.

Comment: HI, thanks, this is answering my question. How to implement this in PHP with the date function. When I build the timestamp it will be with -8 hours for Las Vegas: $time3 = strtotime('2011-03-18 09:49 -08:00'); is there any possibility to enable the DST ?

Comment: @Nik: I don't know PHP at all, but if you want to calculate the difference between two times in different timezones, I'd suggest converting both of them to [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) first, that way you don't have to worry about DST etc at all. I'd assume that there are PHP functions that will do this.

Comment: yes there is a function gmdate() but the result is the same. If I get an GMT offset of -8 hours for Las Vegas and an offset of +1 hour for cologne, then the calculation is 16:16 hours for return and not 17:16 :-(

Comment: I think I found a solution ... I will post the function when it is done ;-)